# Expressing $d\pi_1(de_{1}(u)_{p_1})_p$ and $d\pi_1(de_{2}(u)_{p_2})_p$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Working on a problem related to tangent spaces to product manifolds. The setting for the problem is the following

> Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds and $\pi_1 : M \times N \to N$ the projection map and $\pi_2 : M \times N$ the second projection map. Let $p=(p_1,p_2) \in M \times N.$ Define $\alpha:T_{p}(M \times N) \to T_{p_1}M \oplus T_{p_2}N$ as $\alpha(v)=(d\pi_1(v)_p, d\pi_2(v)_p)$. Show that $\alpha$ is an isomorphism.

I've managed to get the proof to the following point. It's quite clear that $\alpha$ is linear as the components are. Also since the tangent spaces are finite dimensional vector spaces their dimensions agree. It's down to proving that $$\beta: T_{p_1}M \oplus {p_2}N \to T_{p}(M \times N) $$ defined by $\beta(u,v)=de_{1}(u)_{p_1} + de_{2}(u)_{p_2}$ where $e_1 : M \to M \times N, e_1(x)=(x,p_2)$ and $e_2 : M \to M \times N, e_2(x)=(p_1,x)$ is the inverse of $\alpha$. So I'm considering $$(\alpha \circ \beta)(u,v)= (d\pi_1(de_{1}(u)_{p_1} + de_{2}(u)_{p_2})_p, d\pi_2(de_{1}(u)_{p_1} + de_{2}(u)_{p_2})_p).$$

As the differentials are linear I have that $$d\pi_1(de_{1}(u)_{p_1} + de_{2}(u)_{p_2})_p= d\pi_1(de_{1}(u)_{p_1})_p + d\pi_1(de_{2}(u)_{p_2})_p.$$

Here I'm stuck I don't know how to express $$d\pi_1(de_{1}(u)_{p_1})_p$$ or $$d\pi_1(de_{2}(u)_{p_2})_p$$ in any way since they're not acting on anything. If I would have them act on say $h \in C^\infty(p)$, then I would have that $$d\pi_1(de_{1}(u)_{p_1})_p(h)= de_{1}(u)_{p_1}(h \circ \pi_1) = u(h \circ \pi_1\circ e_1)$$ but I'm so confused with this already and don't know what to make of this... Is there some form for these two differentials?

Comment: Are you aware that $d(F\circ G)_p = dF_{G(p)}\circ dG_p$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using
$$d\pi_1(de_{1}(u)_{p_1})_p(h)= de_{1}(u)_{p_1}(h \circ \pi_1) = u(h \circ \pi_1\circ e_1), $$

since $\pi_1 \circ e_1 : X\to X$ is the identity,

$$d\pi_1(de_{1}(u)_{p_1})_p(h)= u(h),\ \ \forall h\in C^\infty(p). $$
Thus $d\pi_1(de_{1}(u)_{p_1})_p= u$. Let's try another one:

$$d\pi_1(de_{2}(u)_{p_2})_p (h) =  u(h\circ \pi_1\circ e_2).$$
This time, $\pi_1 \circ e_2 : Y \to X$ is the constant function $y\mapsto p_1$. Thus $h\circ \pi_1\circ e_2$ is constant and so (by property of derivation)
$$u(h\circ \pi_1\circ e_2) = 0.$$
Since this is true for all $h$,
$$d\pi_1(de_{2}(u)_{p_2})_p =0.$$